# Integrate Solr with Mediawiki

Tags: solr, integration, mediawiki

We're running a mediawiki in our organisation. The standard search engine integrated with Mediawiki provides only mediocre search results and we're trying to improve this situation. I want to use solr, but currently I'm stuggling with integration of the solr search results in Mediawiki. Is there a standard tool or a library that would allow for the integration of solr search results in mediawiki.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not really, but you can try to learn a thing or two from this extension:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SolrStore